# How to reproduce this "apply" example using dplyr package in R?

Tags: r, statistics, grouping, dplyr

I want to use the informative `stat.desc` function in the `pastecs` package to describe many columns in my data frame by a group. Let's take `iris` data set as MWE.
So I do it for each column like this:

```
by(iris$Sepal.Length,list(iris$Species),pastecs::stat.desc,norm = TRUE)
by(iris$Sepal.Width,list(iris$Species),pastecs::stat.desc,norm = TRUE)
by(iris$Petal.Length,list(iris$Species),pastecs::stat.desc,norm = TRUE)
by(iris$Petal.Width,list(iris$Species),pastecs::stat.desc,norm = TRUE)
```

but this is definitely tedious when you have many columns, so you typically want to vectorize on this. After many trials I found one approach using the `apply` and `by()` functions as follows:

```
apply (iris[,1:4],2,function (x) by (x,list (iris$Species),pastecs::stat.desc,norm=TRUE))
```

the `list` parameter is to determine by which group, `norm=TRUE` is a parameter that belongs to the stat.desc to describe normality of the data.

**Result**

```
$Sepal.Length
: setosa
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      4.30000      5.80000      1.50000    250.30000      5.00000      5.00600      0.04985 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.10018      0.12425      0.35249      0.07041      0.11298      0.16782     -0.45087     -0.34059      0.97770      0.45951 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: versicolor
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      4.90000      7.00000      2.10000    296.80000      5.90000      5.93600      0.07300 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.14669      0.26643      0.51617      0.08696      0.09914      0.14727     -0.69391     -0.52418      0.97784      0.46474 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: virginica
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      4.90000      7.90000      3.00000    329.40000      6.50000      6.58800      0.08993 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.18071      0.40434      0.63588      0.09652      0.11103      0.16493     -0.20326     -0.15354      0.97118      0.25831 

$Sepal.Width
: setosa
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      2.30000      4.40000      2.10000    171.40000      3.40000      3.42800      0.05361 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.10773      0.14369      0.37906      0.11058      0.03873      0.05753      0.59595      0.45018      0.97172      0.27153 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: versicolor
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      2.00000      3.40000      1.40000    138.50000      2.80000      2.77000      0.04438 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.08918      0.09847      0.31380      0.11328     -0.34136     -0.50708     -0.54932     -0.41495      0.97413      0.33800 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: virginica
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      2.20000      3.80000      1.60000    148.70000      3.00000      2.97400      0.04561 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.09165      0.10400      0.32250      0.10844      0.34428      0.51141      0.38038      0.28734      0.96739      0.18090 

$Petal.Length
: setosa
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      1.00000      1.90000      0.90000     73.10000      1.50000      1.46200      0.02456 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.04935      0.03016      0.17366      0.11879      0.10010      0.14869      0.65393      0.49397      0.95498      0.05481 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: versicolor
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      3.00000      5.10000      2.10000    213.00000      4.35000      4.26000      0.06646 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.13355      0.22082      0.46991      0.11031     -0.57060     -0.84760     -0.19026     -0.14372      0.96600      0.15848 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: virginica
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      4.50000      6.90000      2.40000    277.60000      5.55000      5.55200      0.07805 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.15685      0.30459      0.55189      0.09940      0.51692      0.76785     -0.36512     -0.27581      0.96219      0.10978 

$Petal.Width
: setosa
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
   5.000e+01    0.000e+00    0.000e+00    1.000e-01    6.000e-01    5.000e-01    1.230e+01    2.000e-01    2.460e-01    1.490e-02 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
   2.995e-02    1.111e-02    1.054e-01    4.284e-01    1.180e+00    1.752e+00    1.259e+00    9.508e-01    7.998e-01    8.659e-07 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: versicolor
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      1.00000      1.80000      0.80000     66.30000      1.30000      1.32600      0.02797 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.05620      0.03911      0.19775      0.14913     -0.02933     -0.04357     -0.58731     -0.44365      0.94763      0.02728 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: virginica
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      1.40000      2.50000      1.10000    101.30000      2.00000      2.02600      0.03884 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.07805      0.07543      0.27465      0.13556     -0.12181     -0.18094     -0.75396     -0.56953      0.95977      0.08695 

R> apply (iris[,1:4],2,function (x,y=iris$Species) by (x,list (y),pastecs::stat.desc,norm=TRUE))
$Sepal.Length
: setosa
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      4.30000      5.80000      1.50000    250.30000      5.00000      5.00600      0.04985 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.10018      0.12425      0.35249      0.07041      0.11298      0.16782     -0.45087     -0.34059      0.97770      0.45951 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: versicolor
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      4.90000      7.00000      2.10000    296.80000      5.90000      5.93600      0.07300 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.14669      0.26643      0.51617      0.08696      0.09914      0.14727     -0.69391     -0.52418      0.97784      0.46474 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: virginica
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      4.90000      7.90000      3.00000    329.40000      6.50000      6.58800      0.08993 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.18071      0.40434      0.63588      0.09652      0.11103      0.16493     -0.20326     -0.15354      0.97118      0.25831 

$Sepal.Width
: setosa
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      2.30000      4.40000      2.10000    171.40000      3.40000      3.42800      0.05361 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.10773      0.14369      0.37906      0.11058      0.03873      0.05753      0.59595      0.45018      0.97172      0.27153 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: versicolor
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      2.00000      3.40000      1.40000    138.50000      2.80000      2.77000      0.04438 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.08918      0.09847      0.31380      0.11328     -0.34136     -0.50708     -0.54932     -0.41495      0.97413      0.33800 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: virginica
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      2.20000      3.80000      1.60000    148.70000      3.00000      2.97400      0.04561 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.09165      0.10400      0.32250      0.10844      0.34428      0.51141      0.38038      0.28734      0.96739      0.18090 

$Petal.Length
: setosa
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      1.00000      1.90000      0.90000     73.10000      1.50000      1.46200      0.02456 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.04935      0.03016      0.17366      0.11879      0.10010      0.14869      0.65393      0.49397      0.95498      0.05481 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: versicolor
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      3.00000      5.10000      2.10000    213.00000      4.35000      4.26000      0.06646 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.13355      0.22082      0.46991      0.11031     -0.57060     -0.84760     -0.19026     -0.14372      0.96600      0.15848 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: virginica
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      4.50000      6.90000      2.40000    277.60000      5.55000      5.55200      0.07805 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.15685      0.30459      0.55189      0.09940      0.51692      0.76785     -0.36512     -0.27581      0.96219      0.10978 

$Petal.Width
: setosa
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
   5.000e+01    0.000e+00    0.000e+00    1.000e-01    6.000e-01    5.000e-01    1.230e+01    2.000e-01    2.460e-01    1.490e-02 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
   2.995e-02    1.111e-02    1.054e-01    4.284e-01    1.180e+00    1.752e+00    1.259e+00    9.508e-01    7.998e-01    8.659e-07 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: versicolor
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      1.00000      1.80000      0.80000     66.30000      1.30000      1.32600      0.02797 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.05620      0.03911      0.19775      0.14913     -0.02933     -0.04357     -0.58731     -0.44365      0.94763      0.02728 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: virginica
     nbr.val     nbr.null       nbr.na          min          max        range          sum       median         mean      SE.mean 
    50.00000      0.00000      0.00000      1.40000      2.50000      1.10000    101.30000      2.00000      2.02600      0.03884 
CI.mean.0.95          var      std.dev     coef.var     skewness     skew.2SE     kurtosis     kurt.2SE   normtest.W   normtest.p 
     0.07805      0.07543      0.27465      0.13556     -0.12181     -0.18094     -0.75396     -0.56953      0.95977      0.08695
```

**Question**

How to reproduce these results using `dplyr` package?

My unsuccessful trial was:

```
iris %>%
  group_by (Species) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(pastecs::stat.desc,norm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Or `library(data.table); as.data.table(iris)[, list(lapply(.SD, pastecs::stat.desc)), by = Species]`?

Comment: unfortunately, I am too unfamiliar with `data.table`, so I like to see an approach using `dplyr` which I use quite often, for `summarise_each` I stuck with the function inside, any idea how?

Comment: Actually, I don't think that `summarise_each` would work here. Here's another "data.table" option though: `melt(as.data.table(iris), id.vars = "Species")[, as.list(pastecs::stat.desc(value)), .(Species, variable)]`.

Comment: Have you timed this operation? Your approach seems to do just fine on 15000 rows by 21 columns....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `dplyr`

```
library(pastecs)
library(dplyr)
res <- iris %>% 
          group_by(Species) %>% 
          do(data.frame(lapply(.[setdiff(names(.), 'Species')],
                           stat.desc, norm = TRUE))) %>%
          mutate(measure = names(stat.desc(Sepal.Length, norm = TRUE)))
```

EDIT: Added the `names` that correspond to the `stat.desc` (Based on @Jaap's suggestion)

Comment: maybe add `mutate(measure = names(stat.desc(Sepal.Length)))` to get a column with the measures

Comment: @Jaap Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: great idea to add the measures, but unfortunately I couldn't pass the `norm=TRUE` to the function `stat.desc`, any idea?

Comment: I think it won't work unless you pass the same parameter to `mutate` line, and may be better to store all in a var say `res`.

Comment: @doctorate I am not sure whether there is anything wrong in the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library("pastecs")
library(dplyr)
res <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%  do(  summary = stat.desc(. ,norm=TRUE) )
```

The resuls of `stat.desc()` are stored as a list that can be accessed like this:

```
res$summary[res$Species=="setosa"]
```

Comment: great! could you explain a little what are `do` and `summary` doing here?

Comment: `summary` is just the arbitrary name of the new column. `do` will allow for a result of arbitrary dimension to be stored in a list.

Answer (score 2):

I know you specifically requested "dplyr" here, but I thought I would also share a "data.table" approach (as already mentioned in the comments).

The basic idea is to make the data "long" first, then use `as.list` when running your `stat.desc` function to get the data into a "wide" format.

```
library(data.table)
library(pastecs)

melt(setDT(iris), id.vars = "Species")[
  , as.list(stat.desc(value)), .(Species, variable)]

#        Species     variable nbr.val nbr.null nbr.na min max range   sum median
#  1:     setosa Sepal.Length      50        0      0 4.3 5.8   1.5 250.3   5.00
#  2: versicolor Sepal.Length      50        0      0 4.9 7.0   2.1 296.8   5.90
#  3:  virginica Sepal.Length      50        0      0 4.9 7.9   3.0 329.4   6.50
#  4:     setosa  Sepal.Width      50        0      0 2.3 4.4   2.1 171.4   3.40
#  5: versicolor  Sepal.Width      50        0      0 2.0 3.4   1.4 138.5   2.80
#  6:  virginica  Sepal.Width      50        0      0 2.2 3.8   1.6 148.7   3.00
#  7:     setosa Petal.Length      50        0      0 1.0 1.9   0.9  73.1   1.50
#  8: versicolor Petal.Length      50        0      0 3.0 5.1   2.1 213.0   4.35
#  9:  virginica Petal.Length      50        0      0 4.5 6.9   2.4 277.6   5.55
# 10:     setosa  Petal.Width      50        0      0 0.1 0.6   0.5  12.3   0.20
# 11: versicolor  Petal.Width      50        0      0 1.0 1.8   0.8  66.3   1.30
# 12:  virginica  Petal.Width      50        0      0 1.4 2.5   1.1 101.3   2.00
#      mean    SE.mean CI.mean.0.95        var   std.dev   coef.var
#  1: 5.006 0.04984957   0.10017646 0.12424898 0.3524897 0.07041344
#  2: 5.936 0.07299762   0.14669422 0.26643265 0.5161711 0.08695606
#  3: 6.588 0.08992695   0.18071498 0.40434286 0.6358796 0.09652089
#  4: 3.428 0.05360780   0.10772890 0.14368980 0.3790644 0.11057887
#  5: 2.770 0.04437778   0.08918050 0.09846939 0.3137983 0.11328459
#  6: 2.974 0.04560791   0.09165253 0.10400408 0.3224966 0.10843868
#  7: 1.462 0.02455980   0.04935476 0.03015918 0.1736640 0.11878522
#  8: 4.260 0.06645545   0.13354722 0.22081633 0.4699110 0.11030774
#  9: 5.552 0.07804970   0.15684674 0.30458776 0.5518947 0.09940466
# 10: 0.246 0.01490377   0.02995025 0.01110612 0.1053856 0.42839670
# 11: 1.326 0.02796645   0.05620069 0.03910612 0.1977527 0.14913475
# 12: 2.026 0.03884138   0.07805468 0.07543265 0.2746501 0.13556271
```

I suppose you could dplyr-ify the answer with something like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(pastecs)

tbl_dt(iris) %>%
  melt(id.vars = "Species") %>%
  .[, as.list(stat.desc(value)), .(Species, variable)]
```

---

#### Update

If you want to stay within the Hadleyverse, you can use a combination of "purrr" and "broom" instead of "dplyr":

```
library(purrr)
library(pastecs)
library(broom)

iris[-5] %>%
  split(iris[5]) %>%
  map_df(~ fix_data_frame(sapply(., stat.desc)), .id = "Species")
# Source: local data frame [42 x 6]
# 
#    Species     term Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#      (chr)    (chr)        (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)
# 1   setosa  nbr.val  50.00000000  50.0000000   50.0000000 50.00000000
# 2   setosa nbr.null   0.00000000   0.0000000    0.0000000  0.00000000
# 3   setosa   nbr.na   0.00000000   0.0000000    0.0000000  0.00000000
# 4   setosa      min   4.30000000   2.3000000    1.0000000  0.10000000
# 5   setosa      max   5.80000000   4.4000000    1.9000000  0.60000000
# 6   setosa    range   1.50000000   2.1000000    0.9000000  0.50000000
# 7   setosa      sum 250.30000000 171.4000000   73.1000000 12.30000000
# 8   setosa   median   5.00000000   3.4000000    1.5000000  0.20000000
# 9   setosa     mean   5.00600000   3.4280000    1.4620000  0.24600000
# 10  setosa  SE.mean   0.04984957   0.0536078    0.0245598  0.01490377
# ..     ...      ...          ...         ...          ...         ...
```

Comment: another *data.table* alternative: `as.data.table(iris)[, lapply(.SD, stat.desc), by = Species][, measure := names(stat.desc(Sepal.Length)), Species]`